# Firefox Multi Wildcard Certificate handling

Tags: firefox, ssl, certificate

I have an issue that only appears in Firefox.
The Situation Short:

1. I use a Internal PKI
2. The CA Root and Intermidiate certificates are imported in Firefox
3. The PKI has signed a SSL Certificate with multiple Wildcard Domains as SAN and one Wildcard that is also included in the SAN as
   CN. (The RFC allowes this)
4. The Certificate is Valid in Chrome, IE, Edge
5. The Requested URL is https://DN.example9.de
6. The Certificate looks like this

:

```
Subject:
CN = *.example8.de
OU = IT
O = MyCompany
L = Musterstadt
S = MyState
C = DE

SAN:
DNS Name=*.example1.de
DNS Name=*.example2.de
DNS Name=*.example3.de
DNS Name=*.example4.de
DNS Name=*.example5.de
DNS Name=*.example6.de
DNS Name=*.example7.de
DNS Name=*.example8.de
DNS Name=*.example9.de
DNS Name=*.example10.de
```

In Firefox I get a Certificate Error:

```
Websites prove their identity via certificates. Firefox does not trust this site because it uses a certificate that is not valid for DN.example9.de. The certificate is only valid for the following names:
*.example1.de,*.example2.de,*.example3.de,*.example4.de,*.example5.de,*.example6.de,*.example7.de,*.example8.de,*.example9.de,*.example10.de

Error code: SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_DOMAIN
```

Can someone explain me why this is so?

Comment: Note that the domain in Subject CN is completely ignored by browsers when any "DNS" SANs are present. It should be okay (and maybe less confusing) to just use a generic Subject with no CN.

Comment: I've just created a test environment and it works for me - no error message.  Double-check everything.